# How to Handle Custom Password-less Authentication with JWT Token?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication

**Idea:**

My Login Page is like this:

[image]

Users can Authenticate via a JWT token given from a trusted system.
*Username* is an *Audience* defined in Token so i can validate that the token issued for that user.

**Problem:**

i have a razor asp.net core 8.0 app and added `JwtBearer` in program.cs with default validation parameters:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer();
```

i want to know how do i properly handle Login in `HttpContext.SignInAsync()` ? how can i add Validated token to Bearer's Authorization header?

Comment: When using JWT for authentication, HttpContext.SignInAsync() is not directly used for JWT login. It is usually used for Cookie based authentication, do you want to use this method which requires using JWT with Cookie authentication？

Comment: yes exactly. in fact i want to use a custom basic authentication (cookie-based) but with no user/pass typical credentials. i want to validate an external JWT for role, claims, ... and authenticate the user via validated token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After obtaining the token, you can use HttpClient to set the request header and add the JWT token to the default request header of HttpClient for authentication in subsequent HTTP requests.
`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwtToken)`;

For verification do you need to use the relevant authentication in the "trusted system" you mentioned, or do you need to create your own? If you use system(like API) to verify, you can initiate a post request and carry the token for verification.If you want to customize verification, you can use the same method. Post the token and username to a verification-related method to perform custom-related token authentication. If successful, you can continue to the next step of cookie verification,If it fails, relevant error information will be returned.

```
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwtToken);
 // create httpRequestMessage
 var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
 {
     Method = HttpMethod.Post,
     RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:xxxx/api/token/verify"),
     Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(loginViewModel), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
 };
// use client to send httpRequestMessage to api and we get a json response back

var httpResponseMessage = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

After successful verification,can create a user information object ClaimsIdentity​, which can represent the method used for authentication, and then use the user identity information created in the previous step to create a user principal object

Finally, use the `HttpContext.SignInAsync` method to log in the user. Method will create a persistent authentication ticket (Cookie) and send it to the client. The SignInAsync method  can accept three parameters:

The first parameter is the authentication scheme name, which is used to identify the authentication method used.

The second parameter is the user principal, indicating the currently logged in user.

The third parameter is the authentication attribute, used to configure expiration time, etc.

```
var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]

{

    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, loginViewModel.Username),

    new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, "MyCustom"),

}, "MyCustom");

var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyCustom", user, new AuthenticationProperties

{

    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),

    IsPersistent = false, // You can change this based on your requirements

    AllowRefresh = false

});

// Log successful login

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```